# Fill 100% width using scaling images 2x3

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get a grid of 2 x 3 pictures to fill to 100% width using scaling images.
But for some reason there's a 12 or 13 px gap to the right of the images. Anyone know how to solve this?
I'm going crazy here!

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
} 

.header { 
  height:200px;
  width:auto;
  background:#22FF00;
}

.imageContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;
  padding-bottom: 26%;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.clearfloats {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">asd</div>

<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/449" />
</div>

<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/449" />
</div>

<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/449" />
</div>

<div class="clearfloats"></div>


<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/449" />
</div>

<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/449" />
</div>

<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/449" />
</div>
```

Comment: A little math: 3 * `33%` = `99%` < `100%`. Try `33.333%` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashem beat me with his comment, but he's right, use

```
.imageContainer {
    width: 33.333%; 
}
```

to lose the gap.

See ***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8tfs4yam/)***.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.imageContainer` elements are set to have a width of `33%`. 3 sets of 33% make 99%, meaning 1% of your width isn't accounted for. You can fix this by setting the width to `33.33%` instead:

```css
.imageContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding-bottom: 26%;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
}
```

---

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
} 

.header { 
  height:200px;
  width:auto;
  background:#22FF00;
}

.imageContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding-bottom: 26%;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.clearfloats {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">asd</div>

<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/449" />
</div>

<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/449" />
</div>

<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/449" />
</div>

<div class="clearfloats"></div>


<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/449" />
</div>

<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/449" />
</div>

<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/449" />
</div>
```