# Moving images to a new line

Tags: html, css

Newbie here.

I am trying to create a page of 12 equal-sized images in a 3 Column * 4 Row layout.

I am having a problem with unwanted space appearing between each row. I am currently using `<br>`, which I know is incorrect, but I don't know the correct way to do it. As I understand it, tables are now considered a poor method?

I currently have CSS :

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: black;
}

.centerDiv {
    width: 60%;
    height:200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#FFA500;
}

.pic {
    border-left: 0px solid black;
    border-right: 0px solid black;
    float: left;
    /*  height: 300px; */
    /*  width: 300px; */
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #111;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #111;
}
```

And my HTML :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <meta name="description" content="description">
        <title>JimithyH</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tilt pic">
            <div class="imgContain">
                <img src="tree-0-0.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tilt pic">
            <img src="tree-0-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="tilt pic">
            <img src="tree-0-2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <br clear="all">
        <div class="tilt pic">
            <img src="tree-1-0.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="tilt pic">
            <img src="tree-1-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="tilt pic">
            <img src="tree-1-2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <br/ clear="all">
        <div class="tilt pic">
            <img src="tree-2-0.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="tilt pic">
            <img src="tree-2-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="tilt pic">
            <img src="tree-2-2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <br clear="all">
        <div class="tilt pic">
            <img src="tree-3-0.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="tilt pic">
            <img src="tree-3-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="tilt pic">
            <img src="tree-3-2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are all your images equal in width/height ?

Comment: For this page, yes, they are square.

Comment: There was a similar question some days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381961 And my solution can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/8tfs4yam/ It's even responsive. ;)

Comment: so you don't need any <br> : when there's no enough space floated elements will start from a new line automatically.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/26381961 is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the comments beat me to it but all you need is to set the width of an image to 33.333%, that way the browser will automatically start a newline when it runs out of space. Personally i'd like to have some padding around the image so my CSS for an image like yours would be:

```
img {
   width: 30%;
   padding: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing to define the width of the  tag that encloses the  tag.

You need to split the body width 100% for every three  and so each  should have 33% (just round off).

so you can mention in css as

```
#tilt pic
{
   width : 33%;
   margin-left : 2px; // as per your requirement
}
```

This will surely works for you.